# Receive messages from a channel by some event spring integration dsl

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

i have a spring integration java dsl code that takes a data from http.

```
...
return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("some url")
...
```

I want to receive messages from some other channel when a request arrives at this HTTP address.
i.e. I want to empty some other channel and receive those messages when this request occurs.
How can i do it?

Grateful,
Sergey

Comment: Would you mind to share that part you would like to trigger? Probably that is really not a "channel", but some source of data which you could simply pull from a service activator on receiving the message from a channel for that HTTP endpoint...

Comment: My service invokes some logic when i calling this url. Then the created messages by this logic sends to server. If i'll call this url again and old messages are still in the channel to the server i need to empty this channel but register(log) or reroute those messages to some other channel. Then put in the channel to the server a new messages. This is my problem

Comment: Huh? I think it’s time to close your question. I’ve just answered to you duplicated one https://stackoverflow.com/q/62553896/2756547